# How to Subset Climate Data Based on Lat Long in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf

Okay so this may sound too noobish but I am working on the Hunga Tonga Volcano and trying to subset different meterological datasets based on specific lat long values to create a reference climatology profile.

To be more specific, I am using the cosmic-2 atmPrf data (bending angle) to create a reference climatology profile. Now the main hurdle is the hunga tonga volcano lies on (20.5532°S, 175.3841°W) which means -20.55, -175.3841 if we are talking about a equal rectangular projection. Now I want to subset data in a -5 deg to +5 deg lat long grid and then average the values for each altitude level.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Oh and I am using python programming language

Here's what I've done so far.

```
def co_locate_profiles(ROprofile, interst_lat = LatBound, interest_lon = LonBound):
    LatBound = [Tonglat - 5, Tonglat + 5]
    LonBound = [Tonglon - 5, Tonglon + 5]   
    if (ROprofile.attrs["lon"] >= LonBound[0]) & (ROprofile.attrs["lon"] <= LonBound[1]) & (ROprofile.attrs["lat"] >= LatBound[0]) & (ROprofile.attrs["lat"] <= LatBound[1]):
        print(f"Profile Co-Located: {ROprofile.attrs['fileStamp']} with Lat: {ROprofile.attrs['lat']} & Lon: {ROprofile.attrs['lon']}")
        return ROprofile.attrs["fileStamp"]
```

Comment: One method is to create a grid, and subsample based on that grid. Combining `pandas.cut` with `pandas.groubpy` you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html to calculate statistical properties. If you have a minimal example (small dataset on which you show what you  tried so far) one can help to give you "real" code. For now you did not provide such information so it is a bit abstract, but I hope that it helps you.

Comment: If you are new to Python you could consider trying my package nctoolkit, which lets you easily subset data spatially: https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html